# Windows 10 not booting due to change in cmd in safe mode

Tags: windows-10

I did a big mistake. I started safe mode with command prompt. Then I used net user user password to change the password .Now when I start my hp laptop it shows hp logo then gets stuck on a black screen

Comment: Shut the computer off, and then start up again. Does it offer you recovery options that you can use. I have seen a similar thing before and resetting the computer is normally the way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I tried it just a minute before tou told it worked.thanks btw.It also changed my password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:  Shut the computer off, and then start up again. Does it offer you recovery options that you can use?

This may help you get going.

Comment: I can then hack into any pc this way?

Comment: It depends on the computer but the idea above works in a number of situations.

Comment: So how can i prevent someone from doing this to me?

Comment: You were able to get your own computer going, and I have done this for clients when they give me their credentials. It is very (very) unlikely a person can take your computer, force it into safe mode without credentials, and reset it back to a working computer. You are pretty safe from this.

Comment: What credentials?the account's pass i changed was my brother's. Which i did not know.I started the pc and did the rest.

Comment: You had it running before safe mode. Also your brother may not have secure his computer properly. Sometimes people try to run without passwords Just out of curiosity, why did you remove the answer?

Comment: Oh,sorry for that.But how more can you secure it you are using a password.

Comment: Thanks.  It depends on the computer. Desktop (including clients' computers) are best secured with a good password (8 to 10 characters including special characters). For a laptop (especially my own) that moves around, I add a drive password so it will not even start up without me. Consider also a Microsoft Account with a PIN.